# Связь многие ко многим в Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Хочу связать тэги с постами, есть три модели:

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :tag_to_post
      has_many :tags, :through => :tag_to_post
    end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_to_post
  has_many :posts, :through=> :tag_to_post
end

class TagToPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

В консоли ввожу `post=Post.find(Id_существующего поста)`
После чего ввожу `post.tags` и получаю ошибку:

> Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant TagToPost.

До того как написал сюда, нашёл вот такую запись: [Rails: Why “has_many …, :through => …” association results in “NameError: uninitialized constant …”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040022/rails-why-has-many-through-association-results-in-nameerror-un), где задача по всей видимости схожа с моей, после чего модели были приведены к текущему виду (*до этого была другая ошибка "nameerror uninitialized constant"*).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить мою проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас

```
has_many :tag_to_post
```

А должно быть

```
has_many :tag_to_posts
```

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно так, правда получил ответ на этот вопрос на другом форуме,но забыл его сюда перепостить.